# What is the Best Practic for Referencing Records in a SQL String

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a first table with book information

```
| id |  title | description |
-----------------------------
|  1 | 'Dune' | 'some text' |
```

I have a second table with bibliography information as text

```
| authorId |                  bibliography                   |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     7    | 'Frank Herbert's seminal work, Dune, was ...'   |
```

I intend to render the biography information on a webpage, and want to know that the book titles are references so I can create hover text.  For instance, when reading the `Frank Herbert's seminal work, Dune, was`, the word `Dune` should appear as blue text that, when hovered over, will show `description` text for `Dune` from the first table above.

I'm not very well versed in SQL and was wondering if there's a proper delimeter technique to do this.  I was thinking something like this for the biography string:

`Frank Herbert's seminal work, [[book title=Dune]]Dune[[/book]], was ...`

Then extracting out any references, in this case the book reference, when data is fetched.  I could use this method to rewrite the string as HTML.

I realize an option is to store the bibliography information as HTML, but I intend this database to be more broadly used, and don't want to assume how the field information will be used.  Can anyone tell me what the best practice for doing something like this is?

Comment: You can store your text as XML and have your own tag for linking and maybe in the future support new tags for formatting like paragraph, bold, italic, itemlist, link to image. With XSLT you can convert it to HTML or other presentation format. As a reference key I would use a unique key like your id or ISBN (will there be only one book titled 'Dune'?)

Comment: Great idea @Conffusion, thank you.  It's a contrived example that doesn't represent the data I'll be using, so I didn't put too much thought into the actual reference.  ISBN would be much better in this case, and regardless I'll make sure it's unique.

Comment: ISBN is *not* a good key for a book. Hardcover and paperback Dune have different ISBNs, as of course prints from different publishers (translations etc). But do add a foreign key `authorId` to your `book` table so you can link them, unless you have planned for a more complicated system.